# SQL Query to add count column using additional attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that I am trying to get info from:
table 1 as c,
table 2 as s,
table 3 as sr

I am trying to display the name and description from table 1, last time from table 2 and number of step_id's from  table 3 with status = 2

End goal:

```
|c.Name|c.Description|s.EXecuted_On|Total Count(STEP_ID) from sr where status = 2|
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT c.NAME,
c.DESCRIPTION,
MAX(s.EXECUTED_ON),
(select COUNT(sr.STEP_ID) from sr WHERE STATUS = '2')
WHERE s.CYCLE_ID = c.ID
AND s.ID = sr.SCHEDULE_ID
GROUP BY c.NAME,c.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY c.NAME
```

I get the same count at the count column, probably need an inner join but could not figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing `FROM` clause, can you update with you complete query.

Comment: And the tables structure, while you're at it.

Comment: How are the tables related?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT c.NAME, c.DESCRIPTION, MAX(s.EXECUTED_ON), COUNT(sr.STEP_ID) as STEP_ID
FROM  table1 c, table2 s, table3 sr
WHERE s.CYCLE_ID = c.ID
  AND sr.ID = c.CYCLE_ID
  AND STATUS = '2'
  AND s.ID = sr.SCHEDULE_ID
GROUP BY c.NAME,c.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY c.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want, but maybe this can hep you.

```
SELECT
  c.Name,
  c.Description,
  MAX(s.EXecuted_On) as MaxEXecuted_On,
  Count(CASE WHEN sr.status = 2 THEN sr.STEP_ID END) as TotalCount
FROM  table1 as c
  LEFT JOIN table2 as s
    ON s.CYCLE_ID = c.ID
  LEFT JOIN table3 as sr
    ON s.ID = sr.SCHEDULE_ID
GROUP BY c.ID
```